# What does it mean by "many times a second"?

Tags: vocabulary

The phrase is from a definition of the word *sample* in a dictionary ([*The Oxford Pocket Dictionary of Current English*](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/sample.aspx)):

> (Electronics) ascertain the momentary value of (an analog signal) **many times a second** so as to convert the signal to digital form.

In the above, what does "many times a second" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Many times a second

Is akin to

> Multiple (many) occurrences per second

(x) Times per second = Has (x) occurrences every second.

For example if I have a strobe light, it may flash 5 times every second. This means that in one second, it turns on/off 5 times.

If I have a very fast strobe light, it may flash faster than I can count, or "many" times every second.

"Many" in this context is often used where the exact number is unknown, or unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

It means `several times a second`, `more than once per second`.

So, your sentence is saying that to convert a analogue signal to digital form, you ascertain its momentary value *more than once per second*.

The term `frequency` can be used for the phrase. It is defined as `the number of times per second` you do a certain activity. So, a frequency of 5 means 5 times a second.

Comment: How does "several times a second" or "five times a second" explain "many times a second"?

Comment: In the context of the sentence provided by the OP, I believe it explains what is asked quite clearly.

Comment: But it's the ***x* a second** construct he's asking about, and to use that in explaining it doesn't really explain it.

Comment: Yeah you're defining a sentence using the same phrasing as the original..."many" wasn't the issue, it's the "times a second" that's really being asked about.

Answer (score -1):

"X times a second" = "X times in each second" or "X times per second".

Using the indefinite article *a* is more informal than *per* but both forms are very common and more or less interchangeable.

E.g. the speed of a car is often expressed formally as *miles per hour* but in conversation you will often hear *miles an hour*